# How to manage phone settings like text to speech settings with your code

Tags: java, android

I am developing a Text-to-Speech application, in my application i have settings which allows user to select language, manage the volume and speech rate.. 
I was able to manage the volume by using the `AudioManager`.
Now my only problem is the language and speech rate, i don't have any idea how to manage them using my application..

can someone give me an example code of this?

Comment: Read the document here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html

Comment: all i want is to manage the main settings of the phone which is the Text-to-Speech settings which is located in voice input and output settings..